# Space between top and bottom in the uppercase text is not equal

Tags: fabricjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilk4t.png)

I have got a problem that the text space between to and bottom is not equal, how should I deal with it? I need both of theme equally for match with p tag in html but now I did not found any properties for config that

Any solutions for that?